# module not setting main files variable content

Tags: python, module, pygame

using pygame, I have made a main menu with a few buttons on it. i can detect when a button is pressed and do something about it.

however the code that controls what happens when a button is pressed is in another file (using getattr) and this seems to be causing some issues.

I am using the variable `menu_open` to control when things relating to the menu should be done. when the game starts up and after the one-off dev warning shows (works fine), it is set to True. everything works as intended until i click on my `new game` button. this should just create a blank screen. nothing happens.

i have discovered that `menu_open` is still `True`. what appears to be happening is that the code that controls the `new game` button is in another file and for reasons i cannot understand seems to be working with a different version of `menu_open` than my main file is. (it's not setting my main files `menu_open` to `False` although its testing print statement prints `False`)

code that controls what happens when the button is pressed:

```
def new_game():
print('starting a new game')
import main
main.menu_open=False
print(2,main.menu_open)
```

start of my program:

```
import pygame,commands #line 1
done = False
menu_open= False #deceleration of menu_open at start of program
game_playing = False
```

code that updates the menu (should create a white screen when `menu_open` is False):

```
def display_frame(self,screen):

    global menu_open
    print(1,menu_open)
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    if menu_open:
        screen.blit(menu_image,[0,0])
        for button in button_list:
            button.draw()

    pygame.display.flip()
```

code that causes the button control:

```
def run_logic(self): #worth noting this is called right before display_frame()
        global mouse_pos,mouse_press
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        mouse_press = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        for button in button_list:
            button.check() #runs the following:

def check(self):
    if self.hovered:
        if mouse_press[0] == True:
            try:
                command_to_call = getattr(commands,self.command)
                command_to_call()
            except:
                print('[DEV]: invalid command')
```

result of print statements:

```
1 True  # button not pressed
1 True  # True here is my main files 'menu_open'
1 True
1 True
1 True
1 True
starting a new game   #button pressed
2 False   #false is the other files 'menu open'
1 True    # True here is my main files 'menu_open'
starting a new game
2 False
1 True
starting a new game
2 False
1 True
starting a new game
2 False
1 True #button released, menu still normal
1 True
1 True
1 True
```

i'm not very experienced with multi-file programming so any help is appreciated.
also may be worth noting my IDE (pyscripter) bugs out alot with pygame.
The button control so far has worked fine. i have made a quit button using it.

if you need any more code from my program feel free to ask :)
also if my code is fine and this is just a bug with python/pyscripter/pygame please say so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to fix this is to move the variable to a separate module. But I'll explain what you're doing wrong regardless.

Presumably the "start of [...] program" is in a file called `main.py`. And normally when you want access to a module you import it by path/filename, in this case `main`. However, the first script invoked by the interpreter is *not* named after its path/filename, but instead is ***always*** named `__main__` regardless of anything else. So the correct way to import it, *not that you should ever do it*, is to use `import __main__` and then access it via that name.

Comment: so any variables i need in more than one file should be in their own file? and what exactly is wrong with using __main__? is it that it requires the main program to be run to work?

Comment: Correct, and correct. If you use the module in anything other than the associated program then the behavior could be undefined.